# finding an element that meet the conditions in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector that looks like this

```
A = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
```

and I would like to write a function that returns True if there is a number between 5 to 9 or False if not

Comment: The documentation for [any](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) should get you most of the way there

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by etmuse, you can just use `any` with two conditions.

```
function output = findelem(A)
    if(any(A>5 & A<9))
        output = true;
        return;
    end
    output = false;
end
```

Call function:

```
>>findelem([1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]) 

returns logical 0

>>findelem([1 2 3 1 6 3 1 2 3])

returns logical 1
```

---

As @beaker correctly points out, you can simply use:

```
function output = findelem(A)
    output = (any(A>5 & A<9))
end
```

Comment: `any` returns a boolean value. The `if/else` seems wasteful.

Comment: Yeah true, I added that in now, thanks. It was more for didactical purposes.

Comment: There was no `else` by the way :P

Comment: I realize that, but "`if` with `return`, otherwise falling through to a default assignment" was less concise.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution uses [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
any(ismember(5:9,A))
```

It checks if any of the elements in `5:9` is present in `A`. If you leave out the `any`, it will tell you which of the elements is present in `A`:

```
>> ismember([1,5,9],A)
ans =
   1   0   0
```

(indicating that `1` is present, but `5` and `9` are not).